# I want to select different lists in TFS work items fields, from the global lists, based upon user group

Tags: tfs, workitem

I am aware that I can use "when" clauses in the allowed/suggested values of the field.

My question is : how do I get the group(s) that the current user is in and how do use this to select different lists?

Answer (score 1):

Put a [`for="GroupName"` or `not="GroupName"` in the `<AllowedValues>` rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-pick-lists?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)(s).

You can have multiple `<AllowdValues>` rules. [All "permitted" rules will be combined into one set of items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/combine-list-types?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).